# How to permanently remove a shared file so it no longer appears in Drive searches

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-shared-folder

I removed a file that was shared with me from Google Drive, refreshed the web page, and confirmed it was gone.

However, the file returned when I searched for it by name using Drive's search bar.

How can I remove it permanently so it doesn't return, and isnt found by searching Drive?